# Hysteresis Image Thresholding

Tags: image-processing

In **Image Processing**, is it possible to automatically determine the upper and lower levels for a Hysteresis thresholding stage?. I have been looking for a while for a paper mentioning any technique for implementing this but I have not found it. Does anybody know any paper or document? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Canny's papers deal with that. More recent material can be found here:

http://www.researchgate.net/publication/222607779_On_candidates_selection_for_hysteresis_thresholds_in_edge_detection

Sandra Sandri